# back up sql on a mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying to back up a database from terminal on a mac for first time

I use Xampp for SQL

But trying to back up from terminal

Trying
myusername$ mysqldump planet > planethealth.sql

but getting
-bash: mysqldump: command not found

I access xampp with following command and no password

/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root -p

Please help, project due tonight

Answer (score 1):

I'm not personally a mac user but you have to find the binary for mysqldump, looking at your xampp path it maybe in:

```
/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysqldump
```

But that is just a guess. If it is you could try:

```
/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysqldump -u root -p planet > planethealth.sql
```

Alternatively if the binary is not in that location you may have to go and install it.

Hope this helps, good luck with the project!

Comment: My pleasure, can you mark as answered so if anybody else comes across this post they know it's correct? Thanks :)